# "Last Name" and "surname"

Tags: american-english, british-english, synonyms

Between *last name* and *surname*, which one is British and which one is American? If I talk with somebody from Great Britain, which one is preferable?

Comment: Surname is technically more accurate: which name goes last depends on the language. But I'm biased, being Hungarian and a names geek besides.

Comment: [Deleted the answer converted to comment by mod as it was an **answer** and **not a comment**]

Comment: Related: [Have American English speakers always used the term “last name” instead of surname?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107803).

Answer (score 19):

COCA has 507 "*surname*" vs 1790 "*last name*". BNC has 315 "*surname*" vs 43 "*last name*". So while neither word belongs exclusively to one side of the Atlantic, "*last name*" is preferred in AmE and "*surname*" in BrE.

Answer (score 17):

As someone who has lived on both sides of the Atlantic, speaking both American and British/Commonwealth English, I would say that, regardless of what the dictionaries might tell you, *last name* is distinctly American usage, while *surname* is arguably British/Commonwealth usage

If you have access, take a look at forms generated on both sides of the pond. In America, I doubt you would find any asking for your *surname*. In the UK, RSA, etc, I doubt you would find any indicating *last name*. And trust me, if you said *surname* anywhere in the US, you may still be understood. You'd probably be excused if you had a noticeable British accent. Otherwise, you'd just sound weird.

The only term that might be equally common in both American and British usage is *family name*, especially in formal documents and the like. For regular conversation however, I think the above discussion holds.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker who has never lived in Britain, I would normally use "surname" although "last name" is what you'll see on forms.

Answer (score 5):

*Surname* would be the normal UK term, although *last name* would be sometimes used and understood.

Answer (score 2):

There is no distinction in American English. Both *last name* and *surname* are used, but *last name* is more common. The dictionaries I checked do not give the term as a British variant.

Comment: Why do you say *last name* is more common?  My sources (BNC, ngram) say the opposite.

Comment: Maybe because I see it and hear it more often. In casual conversations here, nobody ever asks "what's his surname": they say ask what a person's "last name" is. Any government form you fill out will have you list "First Name / Middle Initial / Last Name" as well.

Comment: @z7sg: Robusto said American English, and Peter Taylor's statistics confirm that 'last name' is somewhat more common in the US.

Comment: @Colin Fine But ANC returns 45/22 in favour of surname.  UK government forms use 'last name', even though most people in the UK would say 'surname' imo.  Perhaps that has something to do with political correctness.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only familiar with the USA.  The only place I ever see *surname* is in classic literature.  *Last name* is used everywhere else.